# Converting a list of objects in to a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I could not think of how to give a proper question phrase. I have a class with the below structure.

```
class Obj{
private String key;
private int occ;

// getter and setter methods
}

List<Obj> s = new ArrayList<Obj>();

s.add("the",54);
s.add("the",22);
s.add("einstein",2);
s.add("einstein",6);
```

I need to get the HashMap in the following way. Basically just add the values corresponding to the value field.

```
{the=66,einstein=8}
```

I could not figure out how to implement this. Since a map itself will contain only unique values, I am not sure how to implement this. Is there any method in Collections or any way to achieve this? Sorry am new to java.

Comment: Does not make sense. Try a better explanation.

Comment: There is no `add(String, int)` API in `List`. Plus, a `Map`'s values are not required to be unique. It's the keys you are referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the OP is trying to convert the list into a HashMap, and sum the "occ" values for those with the same key:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> m = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 
for (Obj o : s)
{
    Integer i = m.get(o.getKey());
    if (i == null)
    {
        i = o.getOcc();
    }
    else
    {
        i += o.getOcc();
    }

    m.put(o.getKey(), i); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to use is a hashmap you should do it like this:

```
Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<String, Long>();
map.put("the", 54);
```

And then if you want to handle repeated values like summing them:

```
Long value = map.get("the");
map.put("the", value + 22);
```

So, in general:

```
String key = //...
Long newValue = //...
Long oldValue = map.get(key);
if (oldValue != null) {
    newValue += oldValue;
}
map.put(key, newValue);
```